# resource in spring mvc

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-mvc

I know that there are other topics about adding resources(CSS, Javascript) in Spring MVC, but in my case that doesn't work. I have this error when adding: `HTTP Status 404  The requested resource is not available`.

`mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/"`

My application works properly until this point.

In my index.jsp I've got:

```
link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="c:url value="/resources/css/test.css" 
script type="text/javascript" src="c:url value="/resources/js/carousel.js"
```

Comment: it seems your location is not correct - review it once more, see an easy reference [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/)

Comment: done that, with the same structure and even names for folders and still doesn't work ...@Edi . In log i have                   2015-05-15 18:58:18 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:819 - DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' processing GET request for [/Biblioteca/]
2015-05-15 18:58:18 WARN  PageNotFound:1080 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Biblioteca/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
2015-05-15 18:58:18 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:913 - Successfully completed request    ,   where Biblioteca is my project name.

Comment: If that is the actual code from the JSP that the `src` and `href` are wrong.

Comment: If you wanna post the code or send it to me I can take a look into it. You can msg me as well ( twitter or linkedin )

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I think I solved it by adding a default mapping in web.xml

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

In DispatcherServlet I added :

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

At this point 'HTTP Status 404  The requested resource is not available.' has disappeared, but my resources were not available at all. So i found another way to solve the problem, configuring the base tag like

```
<%
String path = request.getContextPath();
String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
%>
<html>
<head>
<base href="<%=basePath %>">
<title>index</title>
<link href="resources/css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
...
```

And now it works properly.